# Using yb_hash_code in select query in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

For the given below schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.table1(
customer_id uuid NOT NULL ,

item_id uuid NOT NULL ,

kind character varying(100) NOT NULL ,

details character varying(100) NOT NULL ,
created_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
modified_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, kind, item_id)

);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS unique_item_id ON table1(item_id);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS unique_item ON table1(customer_id, kind) WHERE kind='NEW' OR kind='BACKUP';
```

We see that `yb_hash_code()` performs better with SELECT query:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select item_id from table1 WHERE yb_hash_code(item_id) >= 0 and yb_hash_code (item_id) < 1395 and modified_date < date '2022-04-08';
Planning Time: 7.967 ms
Execution Time: 82.929 ms
```

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select item_id from table1 WHERE modified_date < date '2022-04-08';
Planning Time: 0.054 ms
Execution Time: 4618.350 ms
```

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select item_id from table1 WHERE yb_hash_code(item_id) >= 0 and yb_hash_code(item_id) <=65535 and modified_date < date '2022-04-08';
Planning Time: 0.073 ms
Execution Time: 4565.615 ms
```

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select item_id from table1 WHERE yb_hash_code(item_id) >= 0 and yb_hash_code(item_id) < 1490 and modified_date < date '2022-04-08';
Planning Time: 0.148 ms
Execution Time: 84.737 ms
```

But, do you suggest starting using `yb_hash_code()` with `SELECT` query after above [#12094](https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/12094) is fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two queries that takes 4 seconds are doing a Seq Scan I guess. `yb_hash_code()` is pushed down only for IndexScan. See [[YSQL] yb_hash_code() not pushed down to SeqScan · Issue #12096 · yugabyte/yugabyte-db ·](https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/12096)

I think the 3rd one you can force and Index Scan with a hint, `yb_hash_code()` will be pushed down. But, maybe you are trying to do too much with `yb_hash_code()`. It was introduced for a specific case, like doing some parallelization when reading all rows.

The goal of a distributed database is to use it like one database logically without caring about the distribution. When specific placement considerations are needed, we have partitioning and tablespaces.